# Is it possible to merge npm depenencies from another package to the current package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package, yarnpkg

For example, I'm developing my own project package:

```
/myproject
    /package.json
```

Where the dependencies is empty:

```
dependencies: {
}
```

And currently I just want to import all the dependencies from another package, is it possible?

Like if I want to import the dependencies from the belowing git package:

```
https://github.com/iview/iview-admin
```

That is, import and merge the below dependencies into the current package, with some command, is it possible?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "area-data": "^1.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "clipboard": "^1.7.1",
    "countup": "^1.8.2",
    "cropperjs": "^1.2.2",
    "echarts": "^3.8.5",
    "html2canvas": "^0.5.0-beta4",
    "iview": "^2.8.0",
    "iview-area": "^1.5.16",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "rasterizehtml": "^1.2.4",
    "simplemde": "^1.11.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.7.0",
    "tinymce": "^4.7.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.13",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-virtual-scroller": "^0.10.6",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.11.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.12.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.11.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.17",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.1",
    "css-hot-loader": "^1.3.5",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "ejs-loader": "^0.3.0",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^10.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-html": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^5.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.6",
    "happypack": "^4.0.1",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "less": "^2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.0.5",
    "semver": "^5.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "unsupported": "^1.1.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.2.4",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^5.0.3",
    "vue-loader": "^13.7.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.13",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.10.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-uglify-parallel": "^0.1.4"
  }
```

Comment: Why not just copy paste then run npm install?

Answer (score 1):

If your local `package.json` is empty - you can just c/p dependencies.

Also, if your question is about doing this from time to time, with different projects, you can consider using a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-dependencies-merge) that provides such function. 
It also will warn you about any potential conflicts of the versions declared.